# How do I revert a resharper shortcut option?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

I made a mistake and changed the "Go to Definition" shortcut from visual studio's F12, to resharper's ctrl+B. I would like to change that back. How do I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reassign it yourself in `Tools`, `Options`, `Environment`, `Keyboard`:

[image]

You're looking for the *Edit.GoToDefinition* shortcut.  Select "Text Editor", put your cursor in the "Press shortcut keys" box and press <kbd>F12</kbd>, then hit "OK".

Comment: This does not work for IntelliJ IDEA schema.  See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688606/go-to-declaration-keyboard-shortcut-missing/25689351#25689351