# Go to declaration keyboard shortcut missing

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I installed Resharper and it over-wrote my keyboard shortcut for **Go To Declaration**.  How can I set the keyboard shortcut back to F12?

I looked in Visual Studio Options > Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard Shortcut.  There are many shortcuts related to declaration here.  I'm not sure which one to edit.

Image (missing shortcut key)

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I revert a resharper shortcut option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534403/how-do-i-revert-a-resharper-shortcut-option)

Comment: @PatrickQuirk I tried the answer there.  So far it is not working.  My context menu still does not display a shortcut even after assigning F12 to edit.gotodefintion.  F12 also does not take me to the definition.

Comment: My context menu doesn't display "F12" either, but the shortcut works.  Not sure what else it could be then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the INTELLIJ IDEA schema you need to do a few things.  Go to Visual Studio Options > Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard Shortcut.

1. Remove the <kbd>F12</kbd> assignment from Resharper.ReSharper_GoToNextHighlight.
2. Assign <kbd>F12</kbd> to Resharper.Resharper_GotoDeclaration by selecting it in the options editor and clicking <kbd>F12</kbd> > Assign.
3. You may also have to remove <kbd>F12</kbd> assignment from Edit.GoToDefinition.  <kbd>F12</kbd> being assigned to another button causes some bizarre stuff to happen.

   [image]

Now <kbd>F12</kbd> should display in the context menu and function correctly.

**Alternatively**, if the shortcut to "Go to Declaration" has simply become unbound then reset it back to the default of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.  In Visual Studio top menu > Resharper > Options > Environment > Keyboard and Menus > Select IntelliJ IDEA schema > Apply Scheme.

[image]